# asp:dropdownlist change dynamically

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, code-behind

Is there any chance, when I select a row from `asp:dropdownlist`, dynamically change page, execute sql query and after result, change selected row in second `asp:dropdownlist`?

If this isn't possible only with asp.net and codebehind, please let me know how to execute SELECT-query in javascript (may be with Ajax; but I don't understand it) and change second dropdown's selected row.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit of a generic question because there is a couple of options that you could do plus I'm not 100% sure what you want to do. In short you could use AJAX to contact a PHP page which will do an operation on your database. A result it generated and sent back to the client. You could use JSON to hold the data that is getting sent to the browser.

All AJAX does is allow you to get data from another location based on the URI you give. I would use the JQuery library as it makes it easy to implement AJAX.

```
// This will trigger ajax whenever the is a change in the drop down. I am assuming the drop down class is .dropdown
$('.dropdown').change(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "page_change.php",
      data: { name: "about_us" }
      dataType:JSON,
      success: function(data) {
      //The data returned from test.php is loaded in the .result tag
        $('.result').html(data.html);
      // If you want to change page you would execute
      window.location(data.url);    
      }
    });
});
```

page_change.php will then contact your database and generate JSON.

More information about JQuery AJAX here:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

You will need to look at JQuery, AJAX, PHP and JSON to change data on your page.

If you just want to change page on a drop down change I suppose you could store the page name in the option id?

```
$('.dropdown').change(function() {
 var page = $(this).attr('id');
      window.location(page + ".html");    

});
```